# Sharing code between multiple Kiwi test files

Tags: ios, kiwi

I have some Kiwi test helper code that is useful across most of my specs.

What's a nice way of sharing this code across multiple specs (i.e. multiple files)? A category on KiwiSpec might be one option. But that feels a bit off, since I'd be putting code in that category to make things work, rather than because it actually belongs in KiwiSpec.

The ['shared example' feature of Kiwi](https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi/pull/442) (since 4.2.0) seems to be better for DRY in a single spec/file, rather than across multiple specs.

The main reason I can't just call some external code from my test is that this external code isn't inside a test case/Kiwi spec, so its assertions either generate compile errors or warnings.

**Update**

I've tried injecting the assertion functionality needed by the external test helper code as blocks into the helper code. (This has the advantage that my test helper code is not then hard-coded to use any particular test framework.) This was only partially successful: for the test cases where I'm expecting an exception to be raised:

```
[[theBlock(...) should] raise];
```

none is raised. I suspect the problem is that I have another block being called inside the main block which has a raise against it.

**Update 2**

Another possible technique is suggested at https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi/issues/138 by user gantaa, whereby we create a self variable pointing to the test suite object outside the context of the test suite.

Comment: Have you considered custom matchers? I found myself into some situations similar to yours and writing custom matchers really helped with the code reuse.